# Issues when installing Laravel: vagrant up no such file

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, installation

Ive been having a issue with installing laravel homestead, I keep getting this error message:
Everytime I do vagrant up

me-MacBook-Pro:Homestead me$ vagrant up
/Users/me/Homestead/Vagrantfile:17:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/me/.homestead/Homestead.yaml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/me/Homestead/Vagrantfile:17:in`block in '

I have the gen key. I know it's installed.

### This is what my Homestead.yaml file looks like:

ip: "198.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/Homestead/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/laravel-basics/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial for installing homestead 2.0 https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two

Comment: Thanks. Is this how it should look export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"  ?

Comment: Depends on your host OS. For Linux edit `~/.profile` and add `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` to add it permanently.

Answer (score -1):

Add the path `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` to vagrant path file or automatically `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/"`. It will fix it.

After that you have to use `vagrant up`